# Renewal Function and a gamma distribution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I got the following equation, it is not important what $N(t)$ exactly is:

$ \mathbb{P} (N(t)=k)=e^{-\lambda t} \biggl( \frac{(\lambda t)^{2k}}{(2k)!}+  \frac{(\lambda t)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\biggr) \ \text{für} \ k\in \mathbb{N}_0.$

With this equation I get the following:

$ \sum_{k\geq 1} k \ \mathbb{P}(N(t)=k)=\frac{e^{- \lambda t}}{2}\biggl(\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{k(\lambda t)^k}{k!}-\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{(\lambda t)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\biggr) $

I don't get this equation, where is the minus and the $\frac{1}{2}$ are coming from ?
Could someone explain this to me ?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} k(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})=\frac 1  2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (2ka_{2k}) + \frac 1  2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  (2k+1)a_{2k+1} -\frac 1  2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  a_{2k+1}$ [as seen by splitting $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  (2k+1)a_{2k+1}$ into two parts]. Combining  the first two terms here we get $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} k(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})=\frac 1  2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} ia_{i}  -\frac 1  2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  a_{2k+1}$.